# Please suggest any free webserivce for US ZIpcode to Local TIme/ Current Time

Tags: php, web-services, time

I am looking for a free API or webservice that provides Current Time/Local time for US Zipcodes. I want to use it a php application. Or any alternative to achieve what I am looking for would also be very helpful. There is a service that provides local time based on latitude and longitude but there are other issue like hit per day and stuff like that. Your help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.worldweatheronline.com/time-zone-api.aspx  you need to sign up for a free API key, but other than that, the API is very easy to use.

Request URL:-

http://www.worldweatheronline.com/feed/tz.ashx?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=SW1&format=xml

Output:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <request>
    <type>UK Postcode</type>
    <query>SW1</query>
  </request>
  <time_zone>
    <localtime>2010-11-09 17:00</localtime>
    <utcOffset>0</utcOffset>
  </time_zone>
</data>
```